# regex for java string to differentiate between two different strings containing dynamic characters

Tags: regex

I need two different regular expressions for the below string values mentioned;

Source Text 1: `user.tag.<TAG>.<TAGVALUE>`

Source Text 2: `user.tag.<TAG>`

A simple regular expression should uniquely identify the above two strings. But there should be no overlap.  The value that enclosed within `<>` are dynamic. The dynamic values can be anything(including whitespace) except `.` character .

However I used the below regex conditions

RegEx for String 1: `(\Quser.tag\E)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)(.*)`

RegEx for String 2: `(\Quser.tag\E)\.(\w+)\.(.*)`

The Regex for `String 2` will match for the `first source string` as well. I don't want that to happen and I want them to be unique.

Comment: Maybe `^(\\Quser.tag\\E)[.]<(\\w+)>$`? and `^(\\Quser.tag\\E)[.]<(\\w+)>[.]<(\w+)>$`?

Comment: Yeah these `.` should definitely be escaped to begin with

Comment: Be careful with your `.` characters. You have to escape them as `\.` if you want to match a literal `.`. Also, why do you have the `(.*)` at the end of your regexes? That will have it match "anything" which is the root cause for the unwanted match. Please provide text samples and how they should (or should not) match.

Comment: Apologies. I have escaped them now. And added examples as well.

Comment: So, the `>` and `<` are redundant in my first comment. Now, what do you think of `"^(user[.]tag)[.](\\w+)$"` and `"^(user[.]tag)[.](\\w+)[.](\\w+)$"`? Actually, with `String.matches()`, you do not even need the anchors `^` and `$`.

Comment: Also, if you're using Java, the `\Q...\E` should not be used because certain versions of Java have bugs with that. Especially in such a simple case I'd just escape the dot and leave the rest of the text as-is.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew While you are right that `String.matches()` is always anchored it would not make any sense to have capture groups, so I'm assuming that anchoring is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example, use the following regexes:

```
^user\.tag\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$

^user\.tag\.([^.]+)$
```

Note that [`\Q..\E` is buggy](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4803197) in some older Java versions and it's best to avoid it therefore.

Comment: This is almost close to what I asked but `\w` restricts me to use only words and numbers. The dynamic values can be anything(including whitespace) except `.` .

Comment: @stangada Okay, didn't register the part that the dynamic values may be anything, my bad. See my edit which takes this into account.